# Cache data between callbacks

Tags: c#, asp.net

## Short question

How should I store data that is used only by 1 user and between 2 callbacks (2 button events)?
Using `System.Web.Caching.Cache` (not user-specific) and Session (slow) both seem unappropriate.

---

## Long question

I'm loading some expensive data after the user has searched for something.
To re-use this data later, I save it in a private instance variable.

Finally, I refresh parts of the site using an `UpdatePanel`.

Now, if the user clicks on a button in one of the rows this results in another callback.
The data loaded in the previous callback is gone.

What is the most appropriate way of storing this data?

Comment: How much data is there? Is it feasible to give it to the client to be posted back with the callback, e.g. using View State?

Comment: there is a caching framework in .net 4 already which allows different providers based on need.  Which version are you using?

Comment: @TimRogers Potentially a lot of it. I don't think this is something for the View State

Comment: @Dreamwalker **4.0**. A link or something would be a appreciated :)

Comment: And why do you say session state is slow? It's just an in-memory Dictionary underneath.

Comment: @TimRogers That's what I thought, my boss yelled at me for using it :P

Comment: Are you in a distributed environment?  this is relevant to @TimRogers question and any form of caching.  See here for .net 4 caching docs http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Well there are many reasons for not using session state ([I would rarely advocate using session state at all](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/160947/should-session-variables-be-avoided)), but it's not slow. As @Dreamwalker suggests, caching your data query is the best bet.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use Session personally, which should give perfectly adequate performance - and is really your only viable option in a web-farm environment (assuming you don't want to be posting session state around via Form/Querystring parameters - which I suspect you wouldn't want to do for search results).

BTW, UpdatePanels are a bit old hat now.  You'll get much better peformance from a vanilla AJAX call to a MVC controller / WCF Svc method / generic HTTP handler.